# Supporting IQueryable and IList interfaces in a single controller within a Web API: Can anything simple remove this duplication?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Assume that I have a web api and that I have a particular controller that performs an aggregation and projection of the responses from two other resource controllers. Let's call the resources `Baz` and `Inga` and the aggregation `BazInga`.

`Baz` is defined (simplified) as

```
public class BazController : ApiController
{
   private entities.data.DomainEntities Repository { get;set; }
   public BazController(entities.data.DomainEntities repository)
   {
     Repository = repository;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("resources/baz/{id}")]
   public dynamic GetBazById(int id)
   {
      return Get(id: id);
   }

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("resources/baz/name/{name}")]
   public dynamic GetBazByName(string name)
   {
      return Get(name: name);
   }

   private dynamic Get(int id = null, string name = null)
   {
     try
     {
         Repository.Database.CommandTimeout = 120;
         var query = Repository.Baz
                       .Where(filter => id == null || filter.id == id)
                       .Where(filter => name == null || filter.name == name)
                       .Select(baz => baz);
         var baz = query.AsEnumerable();
         if(baz.Count() == 0) return NotFound();
         return baz;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         return InternalServerError(ex);
      }
   }
}
```

Packing the `IQueryable<entities.data.baz>` into `dynamic` is fine for the serializer but I run into trouble with stupid code like this when I want to execute the IQueryable in internal callers, like `BazIngaController`

```
dynamic _baz = BazProxy.GetBazById(id);
List<dynamic> baz = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var item in _baz) baz.Add(item);

dynamic _inga = IngaProxy.GetIngaById(id);
List<dynamic inga = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var item in _inga) inga.Add(item);
```

In order to avoid repetitive walks through the result just to force the IQueryable to execute, I typically refactor `BazController` with a `Fetch` method that isn't decorated with an externally facing `RouteAttribute` and I've been using this technique for a while now.

```
public dynamic FetchBaz(int id = null, string name = null)
{
   return Fetch(id: id, name: name);
}


private dynamic Get(int id = null, string name = null)
{
   try
   {
      var baz = Query(id: id, name: name);
      return baz;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      return InternalServerError(ex);
   }
}
private dynamic Fetch(int id = null, string name = null)
{
   try
   {
      IQueryable baz = Query(id: id, name: name);
      return new List<dynamic>((IEnumerable<dynamic>)baz);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      return InternalServerError(ex);
   }
}

private IQueryable Query(int id = null, string name = null)
{
     try
     {
         Repository.Database.CommandTimeout = 120;
         var query = Repository.Baz
                       .Where(filter => id == null || filter.id == id)
                       .Where(filter => name == null || filter.name == name)
                       .Select(baz => baz);

         return query;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         throw;
      }
   }
}
```

What this does for my internal calls is simplify them to

```
dynamic baz = BazProxy.FetchBaz(name: name);
dynamic inga = IngaProxy.FetchInga(id: id);
```

but as you can see, I've merely traded one style of repetition for another and pushed it into the resource controller.  I somewhat avoid a *ridiculous* level of repetition by only implementing a single `public FetchBaz` method that has an optional param list that mirrors my `private Query` method, which ends up being marginally sane since I never expose my Fetch methods on a route.

This works well for me to maintain clear support for remote and internal interfaces, but the duplication between the `Get` and `Fetch` entrypoints is entirely due to the fact that I can't call `.ToList()` on a dynamic.  I'd refactor my `Fetch` to a base controller class, but can't figure out a simple way to use named optional parameters with a param list, so.....

### Anybody have a cleaner way of doing this that they'd be willing to share?

Comment: Why all the dynamic stuff?  GetBazByX should return a Baz(s), not a dynamic.  Although I typically don't push the filters down that far.  I would keep them closer to the controller, and filter in the method that needs filtering. `public IQueryable<Baz> FetchBazByName(string name) { return Repository.Baz.Where(x=>x.name==name); }`

Comment: For `Baz`, you are right. An `IQueryable<Baz>` could be returned on the route, but consider the case where I want to project an entity to an anonymous type.  Here, I return Baz as a dynamic simply for the sake of consistency and to illustrate the repetition, and for cases where the only client of an api route is the `MediaTypeFormatter`, the return type is a DNC; ergo, I usually return `dynamic`.  It's only when I want to introduce a Home interface that this becomes a valuable point of discussion

Comment: Why would you want to project to an anonymous type that you are using as part of your API?  Doesn't that mean it's not anonymous and should be a well defined type?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm having a hard time understanding what your pain point is, why you are doing what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve.  I've never used `MediaTypeFormatter`, and I'm not sure what you mean by "Home interface".  Yes, you can not (easily) return an anonymous type, and I suppose converting to a dynamic is a way around it, but I'm unsure as to why would would want to in most cases in the first place.

Comment: Re: "defining a type." Not really.  It depends on if I care about the type or not.  I _typically_ only add defined types to an api for de/serialization or if the value of adding one outweighs the cost of adding another maintenance point.  I guess the focus of this question is how to avoid the value proposition of adding a type here so that I can improve functionality without adding a named type.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Re: "Home Interface" Oh....I crossed the streams there. "Home Interface" is terminology from EJB land. A Home Interface is how you communicate between beans without leaving the container and coming back in.  For an ASP.NET Web API, that would basically be that I want a controller to call another controller but I want to avoid having to leave ASP.NET just to come back in on a different route.  (i.e. I want to call the controller internally)  As far as the `MediaTypeFormatter`, that's what handles wire de/serialization.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, unfortunately, I think this delves further into the Web API than I can help you with other than simply if you need to call something and it's used as both an external API (on one controller), but needed as an internal call on another controller, perhaps both should be calling something internal that returns a better (stronger) type.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Re: "unfortunately." That's ok. I appreciate the discussion.  (side note) One thing to keep in mind is that what is *actually* being returned from an API is an HttpResponseMessage, and what is in that message is basically "blah blah blah. Don't care" to the serializer. Using `dynamic` allows you to put anything you want into the Response content without (what I feel are) unnatural histrionics to make the method signatures look familiar to server-side developers. The response is always actually dynamic....

Comment: ...consider the case where a Repository returns no results based upon the calling criteria. The only proper response from an API communicating over HTTP is a `404 Not Found` (which is handled for free by returning `NotFound()` (which returns a System.Web.Http.Results.NotFoundResult) and you can't return that if your method states it is returning a "fake" static type that differs from NotFoundResult, unless you change your returned type to an `HttpResponseMessage` and fill the response yourself. Type `return NotFound();` in a dynamic API Route to see what I mean.

Comment: If a repository returns no results based upon the calling criteria, and multiple results are expected/possible, I would not expect a `404 Not Found`, but an empty collection to be returned.  If you are expecting a single result (like FindById), then `404 Not Found` would be appropriate, but isn't there a global error handler than you can hook into to check for an InvalidOperationException being thrown from a call that returns something that doesn't implement ICollection and then rethrow the 404?

Comment: Seems like a fairly generic solution to that problem since both LINQ's `.First()` method throws `InvalidOperationException` when no records are found, and `.Single()` method throws the same when either 0 or >1 records are found.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Deciding to return an empty array and a 204 response is an implementer's detail (but is generally inadvisable.) I never return singular results across the wire but always return collections (even if that collection only has a single item). It helps reduce cyclomatic complexity of your API and of your internals. I never return an empty array, but instead a 404 Not Found...because -to me(and to 6.5.4 of RFC7231)- that is what happened when the representation was requested, _it wasn't found._

Comment: I could be wrong, but I would think that an empty collection is a valid representation of a resource, and then according to 6.5.4, you should not be returning it a 404.  To me (and to 6.5.4 with this interpretation), the representation was requested, and found, and it contained nothing (or nothing matched).

Comment: @RobertMcKee My opinion is that returning an empty collection leaks an abstraction over HTTP.  Keep in mind that the interface to the API is a list of Resource Identifiers.  My clients are supposed to send me identifiers of resources, and the only thing that generates a 200 in my API is a cache hit or a found entity. An empty array means that for the identifier provided by the client, no resource exists and I choose not to provide a representation for "nothing." To me, that is always a 404...

Comment: ...Note that I don't believe there is a "wrong" here.  If you wish your domain to consider the empty array to be a valid resource, then return it to clients. But as for my service apis, nothing gets returned on a 200 unless it is a valid representation, and I do not consider the empty array to be a resource within my domain.

Comment: There isn't, and I've seen many different types of API's go one way or the other.  I tend to think of a correct functioning answer that is nothing is different from one that is incorrect, or unknowable, or unanswerable being a something different.  AKA the difference from an empty string and one that hasn't been allocated.  Asking for a string that is empty is valid, and the response is valid, but asking for (the contents of) an unallocated string is not.  Or NULLs in a DB, etc.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I think that's where the philosophical dividing line is located.  All "correct, functioning" endpoints are communicated through my entities as hypermedia links. Having a resource identifier provided by a client that does not return any results indicates that they have most likely gone outside the constraints of REST and have provided an invalid URI, and I choose not to provide any additional information other than "you didn't give me one of the URIs I told you that you could send back to me." The other alternative is they are hitting an area of the API that is less RESTful but...

Comment: ...I return a 404 to keep the response interface as consistent across the entire service façade as I can. Say for instance that I've produced an ad-hoc query tool for clients to consume and _they want_ to search `?foo=bar` (clients don't control what they can search for. They say pretty please with sugar on top) There's semantically no difference between passing the API a bad `foo` value, passing an indecipherable route param, and an attempt at a parameter injection attack.